# Label not raising in light mode but raising in dark mode - PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am writing a program that shows the camera feed within a QPixmap. When I press the start button, the camera feed is captured and fed into a method that continuously updates the label image_label.

When I press the stop button, I want to clear the contents of the label so the last frame of video capture does not remain. I do this by raising and lowering a label.

I use qdarkstyle, which applies a stylesheet to the program when the system detects the operating system is in dark mode. Starting the program displays a video as expected, and pressing this button again raises above the camera feed in "dark mode", as expected.

However, when starting the program in "light mode" and raising the label above the camera feed, the label seems to malfunction and not work, despite it being the same lines of code.

The bare minimum code is as follows:

```
from PyQt5 import QtGui, QtWidget
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal, pyqtSlot, Qt, QThread
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPixmap
import numpy as np
import sys
import darkdetect
import qdarkstyle
import cv2
import time

class VideoThread(QThread):
    change_pixmap_signal = pyqtSignal(np.ndarray)


    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._run_flag = True

    def run(self):

        wCam, hCam = 640, 480

        # capture from web cam
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        assert cap.isOpened()
        cap.set(3, wCam)
        cap.set(4, hCam)

        while self._run_flag:
            # Get image frame
            success, img = cap.read()
            if not success:
                break

            if success:
                self.change_pixmap_signal.emit(img)
            # shut down capture system
            cap.release()

    def stop(self):
        self._run_flag = False
        self.wait()


class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        loadUi("mainwindow.ui", self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Hand Tracker")
        self.display_width = 640
        self.display_height = 480
        self.firsttime = 1
        if darkdetect.isDark() == True:
            self.setStyleSheet(qdarkstyle.load_stylesheet_pyqt5())

        # start the thread
        self.gesture.clicked.connect(self.gotowindow2)
        self.startbutton.clicked.connect(self.startvideo)
        self.darkmodecheck.clicked.connect(self.darkmode)

    def darkmode(self):
        print(darkdetect.isDark())

    def gotowindow2(self):
        widget.setCurrentIndex(widget.currentIndex() + 1)  # changes index by 1 to change page

    def startvideo(self):
        # Change label color to light blue
        self.startbutton.clicked.disconnect(self.startvideo)


        self.clearlabel.lower()
        # Change button to stop
        self.startbutton.setText('Stop video')
        self.thread = VideoThread()
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.connect(self.update_image)
        # start the thread
        self.thread.start()
        if self.firsttime == 0:
            time.sleep(4)
            self.firsttime = 0

        self.startbutton.clicked.connect(self.thread.stop)  # Stop the video if button clicked
        self.startbutton.clicked.connect(self.stopvideo)
        self.firsttime = 0

    def stopvideo(self):
        self.thread.change_pixmap_signal.disconnect()
        self.clearlabel.raise_()
        self.startbutton.setText('Start video')
        self.startbutton.clicked.disconnect(self.stopvideo)
        self.startbutton.clicked.disconnect(self.thread.stop)
        self.startbutton.clicked.connect(self.startvideo)



    def closeEvent(self, event):
        self.thread.stop()
        event.accept()

    @pyqtSlot(np.ndarray)
    def update_image(self, img):
        """Updates the image_label with a new opencv image"""
        qt_img = self.convert_cv_qt(img)
        self.image_label.setPixmap(qt_img)


    def convert_cv_qt(self, img):
        """Convert from an opencv image to QPixmap"""
        rgb_image = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        h, w, ch = rgb_image.shape
        bytes_per_line = ch * w
        convert_to_Qt_format = QtGui.QImage(rgb_image.data, w, h, bytes_per_line, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
        p = convert_to_Qt_format.scaled(self.display_width, self.display_height, Qt.KeepAspectRatio)
        return QPixmap.fromImage(p)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget()
    a = MainWindow()
    widget.addWidget(a)
    widget.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

My Ui file is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>Form</class>
 <widget class="QWidget" name="Form">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>1001</width>
    <height>650</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>Form</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="image_label">
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>180</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>480</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QLabel{
border: 1px solid grey;
border-radius: 10px
}</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Img</string>
   </property>
   <property name="alignment">
    <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="startbutton">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>340</x>
     <y>520</y>
     <width>111</width>
     <height>31</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="mouseTracking">
    <bool>false</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border-radius: 10px;
border: 0.5px solid grey;
} </string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Start Video</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="darkmodecheck">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>170</x>
     <y>520</y>
     <width>113</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>PushButton</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QPushButton" name="gesture">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>550</x>
     <y>520</y>
     <width>113</width>
     <height>32</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QPushButton{
border-radius: 10px;
border: 0.5px solid grey;
} </string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Gestures</string>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QLabel" name="clearlabel">
   <property name="enabled">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>180</x>
     <y>20</y>
     <width>640</width>
     <height>480</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <property name="styleSheet">
    <string notr="true">QLabel{
border: 1px solid grey;
border-radius: 10px
}</string>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>Img</string>
   </property>
   <property name="alignment">
    <set>Qt::AlignCenter</set>
   </property>
  </widget>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "label seems to malfunction and not work"? "Not work" and "malfunction" may be very different things. Also, if you want to clear the image of a QLabel, just set an empty pixmap (or just hide the label): showing another label above it is not a valid solution.

Comment: I have already tried to clear the pixmap however nothing has happened. 
By malfunction I mean the label that is raised does not raise above the camera view in light mode, but does in dark mode.

Comment: That's probably because in "light mode" the label's background is transparent. Please [edit] your code and show us your attempt in clearing the pixmap.